# Errors in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have trouble setting up the math mode. It doesn't matter if i use `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` or `\[ ... \]` etc, it always gives me the same error. Only having a formula within the text with `$ ... $` works, but I would like to use the math mode.

Here's my example:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}

y = 5

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The errors I'm getting are the following:

- Missing $ inserted
- Display math should end with $$
- Bad math environment delimiter. \end{equation}
- You can't use '\eqno' in vertical mode. \end{equation}
- Missing $ inserted. \end{equation}
- Display math should end with $$. \end{equation}

Thank you very much in andvance!

Comment: Don't write empty lines in `equation` environment!!!!!!

Comment: poptential duplicate: [Blank lines in an equation and some other similar function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315200)