# Why can't I create an equation in my list?

Tags: equations, lists

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\title{}
\author{Author:\\ \hfill\\ Registration Number: }
\date{Date:}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{}

\subsection{}

\begin{enumerate}[i.]

\item my text
\item my text
\item my text

\noindent\rule{12.6cm}{0.7pt}

\item 

\begin{equation}

            \frac{y[n]}{x[n]} = \frac{1}{2}

\end{equation}

\item 

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This is the outline of the document but I'm getting the error "missing $ inserted ... $". I've never had a problem with using the equations before so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is because you have blank lines within the `equation` environment. Remove them and you'll be fine. We've had this before.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Don't put empty lines in a math environment.

Comment: Here's a source for using blank lines if it improves your code readability: [Blank lines in `align` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10355/5764)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Why `align` and `equation` environment do not tolerate empty lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/328779/5764); [Blank lines in an equation and some other similar function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315200/5764)

Comment: Thanks very much, problem solved. Sorry that it's duplicated.

Comment: This question is not duplicated, you didn't know that the problem came from the blank lines.