# Reported multiple error signs when using the aligned environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

When I was trying to use the alignment environment in latex to write a function, I found it hard to insert \therefore or \because in the environment and there were a few error notice.`From the equation, we know that:

```
\documentclass{article}

%Prevent the ff
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = *}

%Make full use of the paper
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}

%Necessary for Math Mode
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%For items
\usepackage{enumitem}

%Add necessary new command
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}

%1.5 space
\usepackage{setspace}


\begin{document}


\textbf{Problem 1:}\\\\
\begin{enumerate}[label = (\roman*)]
\item
From the equation, we know that:
\begin{proof}
\begin{equation*}[]
\begin{aligned}[]
(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n})^2-1 &= \frac{2+a_n-a_n^2}{a_n^2}\\
{\because} 0<a_n<2\\
{\therefore} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n})-1 &>0\\
{\therefore} a_{n+1} > a_n >0
\end{aligned}

\end{equation*}
We can know that the sequence is increasing.
\end{proof}


\end {document}
```

There were multiple errors, how may I solve this?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what errors were reported.  One that I see is a blank line before `\end{equation}`.  Blank lines aren't allowed in *any* math expression.  It's also highly unusual to embed a `proof` in an item; I don't know whether that will automatically trigger an error (and I can't test), but it's highly suspect.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's all about the blank line! As for the proof in the item, it is required for my homework, that works fine.

Comment: You should also change `\begin{equation*}[]` to `\begin{equation*}`.

Comment: This question might be considered a duplicate: [Blank lines in an equation and some other similar function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315200)