# I'm trying to align 3 equations by "=", but I'm getting this error "! Paragraph ended before \flalign was complete."

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I use the \usepackage{amsmath} and the code for the three equations is:

```
\begin{flalign}
    rez_1[\;] &= \lim_{s \to 0} \left[\frac{2(s + 2)(s + 4)}{(s + 1)^{2}(s^{2} + 2s + 2)}\frac{1}{z - e^{sh}}\right] = \frac{8}{z - 1} \\



    rez_2[\;] &= \frac{1}{1!} \lim_{s \to -1} \left\{\frac{d}{ds} \left[\frac{2(s + 2)(s + 4)}{s(s^{2} + 2s + 2)}\frac{1}{z - e^{sh}} \right] \right\} = \frac{-14z + (14 - 6h)e^{-h}}{(z - e^{-h})^{2}} \\



    rez_3[\;] &= \lim_{s \to (-1 + j)} \left[\frac{2(s + 2)(s + 4)}{s(s + 1)(s + 1 + j)} \frac{1}{z - e^{sh}}\right] = \frac{3 + j}{z - e^{(-1 + j)h}}
\end{flalign}
```

If you could help me, I would be grateful! Thanks

Comment: You've got blank lines between your equations there. get rid of them

Comment: You're a god. Never imagined this could be the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're wanting to space your equations apart more in your source code, one approach is to put a sole `%` on the otherwise blank lines.

Comment: I really wondered how should a "programmer" read this kind of code, but you shed light on this problem too. Another valuable information, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have blank lines between your equations there. Blank lines can't appear in math mode and maths environments and `flalign` is no different.

You should either get rid of them:

```latex
\begin{flalign}
  rez_1[\;] &= \lim_{s \to 0} \left[\frac{2(s + 2)(s + 4)}{(s + 1)^{2}(s^{2} +
      2s + 2)}\frac{1}{z - e^{sh}}\right] = \frac{8}{z - 1} \\
  rez_2[\;] &= \frac{1}{1!} \lim_{s \to -1} \left\{\frac{d}{ds} \left[\frac{2(s
        + 2)(s + 4)}{s(s^{2} + 2s + 2)}\frac{1}{z - e^{sh}} \right] \right\} =
  \frac{-14z + (14 - 6h)e^{-h}}{(z - e^{-h})^{2}} \\
  rez_3[\;] &= \lim_{s \to (-1 + j)} \left[\frac{2(s + 2)(s + 4)}{s(s + 1)(s + 1
      + j)} \frac{1}{z - e^{sh}}\right] = \frac{3 + j}{z - e^{(-1 + j)h}}
\end{flalign}
```

Or comment them out:

```latex
\begin{flalign}
  rez_1[\;] &= \lim_{s \to 0} \left[\frac{2(s + 2)(s + 4)}{(s + 1)^{2}(s^{2} +
      2s + 2)}\frac{1}{z - e^{sh}}\right] = \frac{8}{z - 1} \\
  %
  %
  %
  rez_2[\;] &= \frac{1}{1!} \lim_{s \to -1} \left\{\frac{d}{ds} \left[\frac{2(s
        + 2)(s + 4)}{s(s^{2} + 2s + 2)}\frac{1}{z - e^{sh}} \right] \right\} =
  \frac{-14z + (14 - 6h)e^{-h}}{(z - e^{-h})^{2}} \\
  %
  %
  %
  rez_3[\;] &= \lim_{s \to (-1 + j)} \left[\frac{2(s + 2)(s + 4)}{s(s + 1)(s + 1
      + j)} \frac{1}{z - e^{sh}}\right] = \frac{3 + j}{z - e^{(-1 + j)h}}
\end{flalign}
```

[image]

Off-topic but I'm unfamiliar with *rez*. As you have it, it is typeset as the product of the variable *r*, the variable *e* and the variables *z*<sub>1</sub>, *z*<sub>2</sub> etc. If it's supposed to be a single unit `\mathit{rez}_{1}` or similar might be appropriate.

Comment: Your last remark pertaining to \mathit really makes difference for multi-letter variables. Thanks a lot, mate.

Comment: "can't generally appear" is too weak.  Blank lines are absolutely invalid in math mode.  See [Blank lines in an equation and some other similar function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315200)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I got rid of the 'generally'. I've just been using LaTeX long enough to know there's generally ( :P ) something I haven't thought of!