# How can I place 3 columns of equation systems?

Tags: equations

I need to create the next set of equations in latex, at the moment the only thing I know is to create them independently but I need to place them as you can see in the attached image, thank you very much.

And I also need to label the equation.

```
\[
Roberts=\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0\\
                    0 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}\\
                
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    0 & 1\\
                    -1 & 1
                \end{pmatrix}\\
        \end{cases}
\]

\[
Prewitt=\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & -1\\
                    1 & 0 & -1\\
                    1 & 0 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}\\
                
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 1 & 1\\
                    0 & 0 & 0\\
                    -1 & -1 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}\\
        \end{cases}
\]

\[
Sobel=\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    -1 & 0 & -1\\
                    -2 & 0 & 2\\
                    -1 & 0 & 1
                \end{pmatrix}\\
                
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 2 & 1\\
                    0 & 0 & 0\\
                    -1 & -2 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}\\
        \end{cases}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Off topic: Don't put blank lines within math.  See [Blank lines in an equation and some other similar function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315200)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

(red lines show text borders)

You need to write your `cases` in one equation. Note: this equation is quite long and may happen that will spill out of border in your document ...

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{equation}                  % changed
       \setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}% added
\text{Roberts}
    =\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0\\
                    0 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}\\[3ex]
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    0 & 1\\
                    -1 & 1
                \end{pmatrix}
        \end{cases}
\text{Prewitt}
    =\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 0 & -1\\
                    1 & 0 & -1\\
                    1 & 0 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}\\[4ex]
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 1 & 1\\
                    0 & 0 & 0\\
                    -1 & -1 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}
        \end{cases}
\text{Sobel}
    =\begin{cases}
           G_x = \begin{pmatrix}
                    -1 & 0 & -1\\
                    -2 & 0 & 2\\
                    -1 & 0 & 1
                \end{pmatrix}\\[4ex]
           G_y = \begin{pmatrix}
                    1 & 2 & 1\\
                    0 & 0 & 0\\
                    -1 & -2 & -1
                \end{pmatrix}
        \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Now equation has number. Also are changed size of `\arraycolsep` that equation can fit in determined page layout in above MWE,

Comment: And how can I label it and put the typical number of the equations? Thank you

Comment: @AlejandroFernándezSuárez,as any  numbered equation;  instead `\[` and `\]` use `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation` respectively. See edited answer.

Comment: Oh yes! That's perfect! Thank you so much for all